# Respsonsive - clear after every third DIV on desktop but clear after every second on mobile

Tags: css, loops, count

I have a loop where i display the DIVs with the content in 3 columns for desktop PCs, so i insert a clearing div after every third DIV:

```
<?php if($countcut == 3) { echo '<div class="clearit"> </div>'; $countcut=0; } ?>
```

that works fine.

but what to do when i want to insert the clearing div after every SECOND DIV on mobile and tablet and delete the clearing DIV for the desktop view?

Answer (score 0):

I managed it now with pure css (nth-child).

Desktop-view:

```
.box {
    width: 32%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
.box:nth-child(3n+5) {
    clear: both;
} 
.box:nth-child(3n+4) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Tablet-view:

```
.box:nth-child(3n+5) {
    clear: none;
} 
.box:nth-child(3n+4) {
    margin-right: 2%;
} 



.box {
    width: 49%;
}
.box:nth-child(2n+4) {
    clear: both;
} 
.box:nth-child(2n+3) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

I hope this is a good way to do it.